# Spyder 2.3.9 with IPython 6.0, automatic graphics option gives blank figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, ipython, spyder

Recently I have run into a strange issue with Spyder and IPython.
Whenever I use IPython+Automatic Graphics, while the figure window pops out, it is blank and unresponsive (clicking, closing it did nothing)

Background:
Fedora 25 x64 with kernel 4.10.17
Spyder 2.3.9 with Python 3.5, IPython 6.0.0, Matplotlib 2.0.2

By having two vectors I tried to plot by the following:

```
freq=np.hstack(bFreq)
flux=np.linspace(-flux_range, flux_range, flux_resolution)
# flux and freq are 1D array with the same length

plt.clf()
plt.plot(flux,freq)
plt.xlim(-flux_range,flux_range)
```

Expected: A figure with the plot of flux and freq.
Instead it showed: A blank figure window which cannot be closed

After this the IPython console still works. 
If I plot with inline with the exactly same command it works as normal (I can see the figure inline).

 Initially I thought it was the Tkinter dependency, however, by using the Python console (non-IPython), everything works normally, figure window pops out and I can interact with the graph.

I tried to update qtconsole, pyqt5 and IPython to lastest version with pip3, didn't seem to help.
Would you provide any hints on what could have gone wrong with my configuration of IPython?

Comment: Please update Spyder to its 3.1.4 version and try again.

Comment: There was actually a reason I was avoiding the upgrade:
Everytime I do, I got an error when I start Spyder: Segmentation fault (core dumped) which then it crashed, no splash screen no main window.

It took me a while to trouble shoot but I ended up leaving it at an older version which opens.

Comment: I just tried again now. 
Installed Spyder 3.1.4 with pip3 as an upgrade, start spyder in terminal : Segmentation fault (core dumped).
Uninstalled Spyder with pip3, uninstall Spyder with DNF.
Installing Spyder back with pip3 (to get 3.1.4 directly), same error when opening.

Finally, uninstalling Spyder with pip3, using DNF to install Spyder 2.3.9, then Spyder works again.

Comment: You have to check what's causing the segmentation fault because Spyder 2.3 is unmaintained now, and not compatible with IPython 6.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the status of Spyder 2.3, I should not try to make it work with IPython 6 in this case.

I have tried and almost able to say it has something to do with the qt5 version. With pip3, I could install and upgrade PyQt5, however the installation of qt5 failed (when I tried to install, it ran so the existing version was not up-to-date. It failed with "No files/directories in /tmp/pip-build-yz2dx2g0/python-qt5/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)". Maybe without the latest version Spyder 3 wasn't able to run? Just my speculation, I will try to install it manually later.